# Overloading the I/O operators for a linked list

Tags: c++, input, linked-list, operator-overloading

I'm trying to read and print a polynomial represented as a linked list by overloading the input and output operators. I have to overload them two times: once in the class node (for reading and printing a single node) and the other time in the class polynomial (using the already implemented I/O overload for nodes).
However the friend functions that i use to overload the I/O for the polynomial can't access the private members of the class node (class that is a friend of class polynomial).

Function "inserare" just adds a node to the polynomial.
My code:

```
using namespace std;
class nod
{
    friend class polinom;
    int exp,coef;
    nod *urm;
    friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const nod &X );
    friend istream &operator>>( istream &input, nod &X );
};
ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const nod &X )
{
    if(X.coef==0) output<<0;
    else if(X.exp==0)
    {
        if(X.coef>0) output<<"+"<<X.coef;
        else output<<X.coef;
    }
    else if(X.coef>0)
    {
        if(X.coef==1&&X.exp==1) output<<"+"<<"x";
        if(X.coef==1&&X.exp!=1) output<<"+"<<"x^"<<X.exp;
        if(X.coef!=1&&X.exp==1) output<<"+"<<X.coef<<"*x";
        if(X.coef!=1&&X.exp!=1) output<<"+"<<X.coef<<"*x^"<<X.exp;
    }
    else
    {
        if(X.coef==-1&&X.exp==1) output<<"-"<<"x";
        if(X.coef==-1&&X.exp!=1) output<<"-"<<"x^"<<X.exp;
        if(X.coef!=-1&&X.exp==1) output<<X.coef<<"*x";
        if(X.coef!=-1&&X.exp!=1) output<<X.coef<<"*x^"<<X.exp;
    }
    return output;
}
istream &operator>>( istream &input, nod &X )
{
    input>>X.coef;
    input>>X.exp;
    X.urm=NULL;
    return input;
}
class polinom
{
    nod *prim,*curent;
public:
    polinom();                                      //constructor
    ~polinom();                                     //destructor
    polinom(const polinom& p);                      //copy constructor
    void inserare(nod *aux);
    friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const polinom &X );
    friend istream &operator>>( istream &input, polinom &X );
};

ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const polinom &X )
{
for(nod* temp = X.prim; temp!= NULL; temp = temp->urm)
    output<<temp;
    return output;
}
void polinom::inserare(nod *aux)
{
    if(prim==NULL&&aux->coef==0)
    {
        prim=aux; 
        curent=prim;
    }
    if(aux->coef)
    {
        if(prim==NULL||prim->exp>aux->exp) 
        {
            aux->urm=prim;
            prim=aux;
            curent=prim;
        }
        else 
        {
            curent=prim;
            while(curent->urm&&curent->urm->exp<=aux->exp)
            {
                curent=curent->urm;
            }
            if(curent->exp==aux->exp)
            {
                curent->coef=curent->coef+aux->coef;
                return;
            }
            if(curent->urm==NULL) curent->urm=aux;
            else
            {
                aux->urm=curent->urm;
                curent->urm=aux;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
istream &operator>>( istream &input, polinom &X )
{
    nod temp;
    do
    {
        input>>temp;
        X.inserare(&temp);
    }
    while(temp.coef);
    return input;
}
```

Comment: In this section of code `ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const polinom &X )
{
for(nod* temp = X.prim; temp!= NULL; temp = temp->urm)
    output<<temp;
    return output;
}
` you probably want to dereference temp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another set of `friend` declarations so that the extractor/inserter for the `polynom` can access the node's data members:

```c++
class nod
{
    friend class polinom;
    int exp,coef;
    nod *urm;

    friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const nod &X );
    friend istream &operator>>( istream &input,        nod &X );

    friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const class polinom &X );
    friend istream &operator>>( istream &input,        class polinom &X );
};
```

Comment: I also have a problem because i overload the extractor for class 'nod', but when i try to print the polynomial it crashes because the elements of the polynomial are '*nod.' How do i print those? Do i need to change the extractor from printing 'nod' to printing '*nod'?

Comment: @user3057352 You probably want it to print nod. I can see in your `polynom` inserter you're doing `output<<temp;` which will print the pointer and not the actual node. I don't know where the crash is coming from though. You should use your debugger and if all else fails, post another question